# jqplot tickOptions formatString options

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I'm incredibly new to web dev. What I'm finding frustrating are the options used in the `axesRendererDefaults` options in `jqplot`.

According to this [link](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisTickRenderer-js.html#%24.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer.formatString):

the way to specify how a tick will appear on the axis (either X or Y) will be determined by what is specified by the `formatString: ''` option.

What options are available for `formatString` option? In the tutorial given on the `jqplot` page, they pass options such as: `%d`, `$%d` and `%n`. How do I find the full list of options available?

Are these formatting options separate from `jqplot` and actually a property of `jQuery`?

Answer (score 12):

The format commands are similar (if not identical) to those for the sprintf function.

A decent reference for these is http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html

e.g.        yaxis: { tickOptions: {formatString: '%.2f'} }

will output a floating point number to 2 decimal places.

Comment: there is a section in the git hub repo of the project: https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/ "JavaScript printf/sprintf functions".

Answer (score 5):

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html

> Accecptable format codes are:
>
> ```
> Code    Result                  Description
>             == Years ==
> %Y      2008                Four-digit year
> %y      08                  Two-digit year
>             == Months ==
> %m      09                  Two-digit month
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation: https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/ in the last section: "JavaScript printf/sprintf functions", jqplot uses "sprintf for JS"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the formatString is the same as used by Highcharts and is a subset of PHP's strftime function. Here's a link to to Highcharts [doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29) about it.